# Making a Point class in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Right now I am using std::pair to represent a 2d point in c++. However, I am getting annoyed with having to write

```
typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;

Point difference = Point(p2.first - p1.first,
                         p2.second - p1.second);
```

instead of being able to overload operator+ and operator-.

So, my question is, to make my Point class, should I

- Publicly derive from std::pair and add my own member functions? This is nice because all my code can stay the same. I am not going to be doing anything like `std::pair<double, double>* p = new Point;` so I don't have to worry about things like virtual destructors.
- Roll my own Point class, which is annoying since I am duplicating std::pair's functionality, however I am "doing it the pure way".
- Make template specializations of operator+ and operator- for std::pair, which admittedly I don't remember if they go in source or header files.

I guess it's up for debate, I'd really like to do #1 but I don't know if it's a bad idea since I've heard that inheriting from STL is a no-no.

Comment: FYI -- the reason inheriting from the STL is a no-no is that it does not have a virtual destructor.  So, if you deleted your own class through a pointer to the STL base type, your destructor would not be called.

Comment: I said I wouldn't do that in the question.

Comment: Didn't think you would; just thought it would be helpful to provide the reason why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could roll your own Point class, but use std::pair internally to store the data. This prevents the inheritance from STL issue, but still uses std::pair's functionality.

Comment: +1. If you happen to read Code Complete, it suggests this exact practice: If [the class Point] *is* a [std::pair], then inherit. Otherwise, the [std::pair] should be stored as a private member, and [Point] should instead define its own interface. "point.first" doesn't make sense; point.x does.

Comment: That's probably where I got the idea from. That book rocks!

Comment: I understand why inheriting from `stl::pair` isn't good; but why even use `stl::pair` in the first place? What features of `stl::pair` are relevant to `Point`? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but ordering, `swap`, `get`, various constructors all seem to be irrelevant for `Point`.

Answer (score 2):

Better than rolling your own: grab an existing free Vector/Point library.  One recommendation: the one attached to [Essential Math for Games Programmers](http://www.essentialmath.com/).  You can use whatever library you find as a starting point, then optimize / specialize / tweak from there.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be in favour of creating your own Point class and use either private inheritance or composition if you want to employ std::pair's functionality. The problem with the typedef (as I am sure you are aware) is that any function you write that takes a Point will also be usable by anything represented as a std::pair<double, double>, which may not be valid.

With this in mind, another option exists of just creating some free builder functions like

```
Point addPoints(const Point& p1, const Point& p2);
Point diffPoints(const Point& p1, const Point& p2);
```

(the function names could be better).

Answer (score 1):

One other option might be to make you own Point class, and have your class "own" a std::pair that represents the point coordinates.

A lot of times a "HAS A" (composition) relationship is preferable over an "IS A" (inheritance) relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Best Practices" would say to roll your own Point class.  This way, you can make it 3D much easier down the road.

Comment: there is absolutely no need for 3d. It's for a game. A 2d game.

Answer (score 1):

Private inheritance aka inheritance of implementation, is your friend.

This follows logically: a Point is NOT a std::pair, you don't want to have a public up-cast conversion from Point to std::pair, but you do want to use std::pair's internals.

The other possibility is to a has-a relationship, or composition: each Point has-a privbate std::pair it uses internally.

In point of fact, there's not much difference between composition and private inheritance, except that in the latter you can force an up-cast to std::pair in a Point member function.

Answer (score 0):

Roll your own Point class.  This will allow you to do any number of things with it in the future.  Specifically, I have solved this sort of problem before, and what I have found to be useful is to define my own Point structure, and create a Point class which inherits from it.

Full disclosure: I do not like the STL very much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't publicly inherit from std::pair because std::pair has a operator< but your Point should not have.